# Find branch of a tag on remote git repository

Tags: git, tags, branch

I'm trying to automate buildsteps with a gui and want to create a json-file with all available tags and branch-heads for selection.
I can already list all branches and tags in a repository by using

```
git ls-remote --tags/heads url-of-repo
```

Now I want to know, which tag belongs to a branch.
I could do something like

```
git branch --contains tags/<tag>
```

But I want to avoid checking out all repositories locally to just get this information.
Maybe there's a command to directly show all tags of a branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a clone, a bare one,

```
git clone --bare url-of-repo
```

Every time you want to list the branches, update the branches and tags first,

```
cd path-to-the-bare-repo
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

and then run

```
git branch --contains tags/<tag>
```

I'd recommend [git for-each-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), which allows to format the output and is more script-friendly. For example,

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --contains tags/<tag> --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)"
```

If you don't want to use `cd` in the script, you could also export `GIT_DIR` and unset it.

```
export GIT_DIR=path-to-the-bare-repo
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
git for-each-ref refs/heads --contains tags/<tag> --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)"
unset GIT_DIR
```

or simply

```
GIT_DIR=path-to-the-bare-repo git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
GIT_DIR=path-to-the-bare-repo git for-each-ref refs/heads --contains tags/<tag> --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)"
```

If you don't want to make a local clone, and you have access to the hosting server. Another option is to run a web service to query the branches in the repository hosted in the server. You could use `django` to write and run such a service in several minutes.

Comment: Thanks, the --bare command is exactly what I needed for this! :)